# How to handle Google and Facebook authentication with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have implemented Google and Facebook authentication in my Firebase project. If I'm signed in with Google, and I sign-out, and right after that if I try to sign-in again with Facebook (the same email address), I get:

> An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.

I read is a know issue but I don't know how to handle it, because when I sign-in with Facebook, I get that message right after I sign-in, the sign-in process being successful. What is the best option to to handle this?

- Sign-out the user from Facebook and indicate he/she must use Google authentication? It's some kind of weird since I would like to know that before I sign-in with Facebook?
- Remove the Facebook authentication?

My goal is to know somehow that a particular email address was already used for a Google sign-in and when the user attempts to sign-in with Facebook, to show a message but without the need of signing in with Facebook. How to handle this?